# C++: Problem in finding code execution time

Tags: c++

To find the execution time of my code as given below, I have written a `Timer` class.

```
Timer::StartTimer();
DoOperation();
cout<<"Time elapsed: "<<Timer::GetTime();
```

I get error that startTime and endTime are undefined. I couldn't quite get the problem. Can you please help.

File:Timer.h

```
#include <sys/time.h>

class Timer
{
    static timeval startTime, endTime;

public:
     static void StartTimer();
     static long int GetTime();
};
```

File: Timer.cc

```
#include "Timer.h"

void Timer::StartTimer()
{
    gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
}

long int Timer::GetTime()
{
    long int seconds, useconds, mtime;
    gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);
    seconds  = endTime.tv_sec  - startTime.tv_sec;
    useconds = endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec;
    mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;
    return(mtime);
}
```

Comment: Do you include Timer.h in your program? Do you link to the implementation of Timer?

Comment: Is there any problem with the usage of `static`?

Comment: @DumbCoder g++ is the compiler

Comment: Anyway why are you using `static` members? Unless you've some weird needs I think it would be better to have normal members instead of static ones...

Comment: Or use a namespace called Timer rather than a class.

Answer (score 9):

In timer.cc you need:

```
timeval Timer::startTime;
timeval Timer::endTime;
```

See this [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12)

As someone else has pointed out though making this *all* static is "unusual" design and might lead to problems if you tried to use this code in multiple places at once. Probably you want to make none of it static and have an instance when you use it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to instantiate static member variables.

Add this to your `Timer.cc`:

```
timeval Timer::startTime;
timeval Timer::endTime;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would be better of using a namespace instead of class if everything is static

You need to define Timer::endTime and Timer::startTime